# How to expose endpoints with spring boot and oauth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I need to expose several endpoints on my spring boot application. I used oauth2 to implement security using tokens, but need a couple endpoints to be public and not requiring authorization token.

I've tried (from several articles I found) implementing a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
    httpSecurity
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers('/actuator/jolokia', '/graphiql', '/voyager')
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
}
```

}
, but to no avail, the endpoints keep asking for a token to be accessed

The `pom.xml` dependency I used for enabling oauth is this:
 `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>     </dependency>`

Also, this is the config class for the authorization server for oauth:

```
@Component
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Value('${application.oauth.clientId}')
String clientId

@Value('${application.oauth.secret}')
String clientSecret

@Value('${application.oauth.accessTokenExpirationSeconds}')
Integer accessTokenExpirationSeconds

@Value('${application.jwt.key}')
String jwtKey

AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

AuthorizationServerConfiguration(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        this.authenticationManager =     authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()
}

@Override
void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()
    String encoded = passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret)

    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient(clientId)
            .secret(encoded)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
            .scopes("all")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenExpirationSeconds)
}

@Override
void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
}

@Bean
JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter()
    converter.setSigningKey(jwtKey)
    converter.setVerifierKey(jwtKey)

    converter.afterPropertiesSet()
    converter
}

@Bean
TokenStore tokenStore() {
    new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter())
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without `.antMatcher("/**")`?

Comment: yes, still asking for token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SecurityConfig you need to join the separate statements together with .and() otherwise they are all concatenated together in a single statement.

Try this:

```
httpSecurity
  .antMatcher("/**")
  .authorizeRequests()
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests().antMatchers('/actuator/jolokia', '/graphiql', '/voyager').permitAll()
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```